How to automatically generate constructors in Java using Neovim
I'm currently using Eclipse's Language Server Protocol (LSP) with Mason for Java development. While it generates getters and setters for my classes, I haven't found an option to automatically generate constructors.
Is there a way to auto-generate constructors using Eclipse LSP or with any other extension?
I've also tried using Eclim, which is designed for Vim rather than Neovim and the project appears to have been abandoned by its developer, so I don't consider it a viable option.
